# Some way to list all Jenkins jobs with their health score on Browser

Tags: jenkins

How can I display all the Jenkins job name with their health scores on the web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link will help you better to understand the `Jenkins REST API`.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Othe way is to use `tree` in th url

```
http://localhost:8080/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,healthReport[score]]
```

This will print job names along with their health scores on browser.

Comment: Thanks Maverick...!! The tree in the URL is very helpful..It's displaying what I was expected.